Quiero pausar la radio con un botón aparte, pero no hace la funcionalidad deseada, alguien me podría darle solución?



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Control de Radio</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px">
    
    <div id="lunaradio" style='width:100%; height:10px;background-image: url("https://www.cutralcoalinstante.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/operador-de-radio.jpeg"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
      border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      border: none;'>

    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
    <button id="pauseButton">Pausar</button>
    <input type="range" id="volumeControl" min="0" max="100" value="95">
    <div id="lunaradio-container" style="width:100%; height:50px;"></div>

    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ai2ny5smsk07k7m/lunaradio.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var audioPlayer = $("#lunaradio-container").lunaradio({
                userinterface: "small",
                backgroundcolor: "rgba(9,15,25,0.8)",
                fontcolor: "#FFFFFF",
                hightlightcolor: "#FF0000",
                fontname: "Saira Condensed",
                googlefont: "Saira+Condensed:wght@100",
                fontratio: "0.3",
                radioname: "Radio La Patrona 105.7 FM",
                scroll: "true",
                coverimage: "https://i.ibb.co/K9WtsXV/LA-PATRONA-222.png",
                usevisualizer: "real",
                coverstyle: "animated",
                visualizertype: "6",
                multicolorvisualizer: "true",
                color1: "dc143c",
                color2: "f1666d",
                color3: "e6f62f",
                color4: "#e6f62f",
                itunestoken: "1000lIPN",
                metadatatechnic: "corsproxy",
                ownmetadataurl: "",
                streamurl: "https://stream.zeno.fm/a536jtganoeuv",
                streamtype: "radiozeno",
                icecastmountpoint: "/radio.mp3",
                radionomyid: "",
                radionomyapikey: "",
                radiozenoid: "utztqpdbt0hvv",
                radiojarid: "",
                radiocoid: "",
                shoutcastpath: "/stream",
                shoutcastid: "1",
                streamsuffix: "",
                metadatainterval: "20000",
                volume: "95",
                debug: "false",
                autoplay: "true",
            });

        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Esperar a que se cargue completamente la biblioteca lunaradio
            $("#lunaradio-container").on("lunaradio-ready", function() {
                // La biblioteca lunaradio se ha cargado completamente, ahora podemos acceder a sus módulos
                $("#playButton").on("click", function() {
                    window.luRadioModules["lunaradio-container"].playMode();
                });

                $("#pauseButton").on("click", function() {
                    window.luRadioModules["lunaradio-container"].stopMode();
                });

                $("#volumeControl").on("input", function() {
                    var volume = $(this).val();
                    window.luRadioModules["lunaradio-container"].animateVolume(volume);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Problema al pausar la reproducción en el reproductor de audio lunaradio:
Allí intenté hacer las peticiones de reproducir, pausar o control de volumen, pero ninguna me ha funcionado. No sé que estaré haciendo mal.
La idea es que la radio pueda pausarse a la hora de pulsar el botón "pausar" y esta se detenga, también el botón de reproducir pueda arrancar la reproducción, o al igual que el control de volumen, también se pueda subir o bajar volumen, lo que más necesito es el de pausa, creería que ya con eso puedo entenderle a las demás funciones.

En el código de lunaradio que tienes en el dropbox tienes esto
e.fn.lunaradio = function(i) {
var a = "string" == typeof i,

ahora para el volúmen vi en su script que modifican localstorage
window.localStorage.setItem(n + "volume", we)

por lo cual intuyo que le podemos mandar cadenas... revisamos un poco más y vemos que dice
e.addEventListener("play", function() {
                        xt("checkaudio play"), xt("autoplay is allowed by browser"), re = "true"
}, !1)

eso significa que en esa sección vienen las cadenas que se le pasan para llamar a las funciones
así que con unos pequeños cambios...


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Control de Radio</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px">

  <div id="lunaradio" style='width:100%; height:10px;background-image: url("https://www.cutralcoalinstante.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/operador-de-radio.jpeg"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
      border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      border: none;'>

    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
    <button id="pauseButton">Pausar</button>
    <input type="range" id="volumeControl" min="0" max="100" value="95">
    <div id="lunaradio-container" style="width:100%; height:50px;"></div>

    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ai2ny5smsk07k7m/lunaradio.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var audioPlayer = $("#lunaradio-container").lunaradio({
          userinterface: "small",
          backgroundcolor: "rgba(9,15,25,0.8)",
          fontcolor: "#FFFFFF",
          hightlightcolor: "#FF0000",
          fontname: "Saira Condensed",
          googlefont: "Saira+Condensed:wght@100",
          fontratio: "0.3",
          radioname: "Radio La Patrona 105.7 FM",
          scroll: "true",
          coverimage: "https://i.ibb.co/K9WtsXV/LA-PATRONA-222.png",
          usevisualizer: "real",
          coverstyle: "animated",
          visualizertype: "6",
          multicolorvisualizer: "true",
          color1: "dc143c",
          color2: "f1666d",
          color3: "e6f62f",
          color4: "#e6f62f",
          itunestoken: "1000lIPN",
          metadatatechnic: "corsproxy",
          ownmetadataurl: "",
          streamurl: "https://stream.zeno.fm/a536jtganoeuv",
          streamtype: "radiozeno",
          icecastmountpoint: "/radio.mp3",
          radionomyid: "",
          radionomyapikey: "",
          radiozenoid: "utztqpdbt0hvv",
          radiojarid: "",
          radiocoid: "",
          shoutcastpath: "/stream",
          shoutcastid: "1",
          streamsuffix: "",
          metadatainterval: "20000",
          volume: "95",
          debug: "false",
          autoplay: "true",
        });


        // Esperar a que se cargue completamente la biblioteca lunaradio

        // La biblioteca lunaradio se ha cargado completamente, ahora podemos acceder a sus módulos
        $("#playButton").on("click", function() {
          audioPlayer.lunaradio("play");

        });

        $("#pauseButton").on("click", function() {
          audioPlayer.lunaradio("pause");
        });

        $("#volumeControl").on("input", function() {
          var volume = $(this).val();

          console.log(volume / 100)
          window.localStorage.setItem("1volume", volume / 100)
          //audioPlayer.lunaradio("volume", volume/100)

        });

      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>



Ahora respecto al localstorage no tuve forma de probarlo porque como verás me sale el error

"message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",

así que espero haberle ayudado.

Gracias, funciona a la perfección, tienes mis respetos estimado.
